# VBA application.run, MAc excel 2016

Tags: macos, excel, vba

Once again thanks in advance for your help.

I am having trouble using application.run, it does not report any error but the code crashes. The project is big and application.run was the simplest way I found to pass a function as an argument...
I simplified the issue to this:

```
MsgBox Application.Run("Application.WorksheetFunction.Var_S", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:B974"))
```

This is simplified, but I cannot manage to get even this to work.

However the following gives the intended result hence the issue is from the use of application.run and not the var function itself.

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Var_S(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:B974"))
```

Hence I know the issue comes from the way I use application.run. As I said no error is reported but the code stops. nothing is returned and anything after application.run is not executed..
My guess is that I do not have the correct syntax, but I could not find lots of documentations about this. Based on what I read this is supposed to be the correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Application.Run you can use

```
MsgBox CallByName(Application.WorksheetFunction, "Var_S", VbMethod, _
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:B974"))
```

Comment: This alternative worked great for me. thanks.   

Yet If anyone knows why aplication.run did not, work i'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Function `Var_S` returns a value.  You're not getting an error because it's running properly.  In example #2 you're telling it what to with the returned value. What should it be doing with the response in example #1?  If you'd like to simply further as an example, instead the `Var_S` function, try it with the `Now()` function, which returns current date:  `Application.Run "now()"` ...  again, it runs the function just fine.  `Application.Run` **runs** a function, whereas `MsgBox` **displays** data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I tried msgbox application.run.... but this does not display anything.    
In my actual code I have a = application.run.... so a should take the value returned but it does not. The code just stops. Just like with msgbox application.run...

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: Google examples of using `application.run`, there are plenty of examples and tutorials to bring you up to speed.

Comment: maybe try an alternative way 'MsgBox CallByName(Application.WorksheetFunction, "Var_S", VbMethod, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:B974"))' or 'MsgBox Application.Evaluate("=VAR.S(Data!B3:B974)")

Comment: @Hubisan Awesome the CallByName alternative worked perfectly. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it. 
Out of curiosity, do you know why application.run did not work?